# Incorporating a Angular SPA into an existing web-site. Routing problems

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

So as a proof of concept, I built a Angular SPA to demonstrate to the rest of my team its potential. They were impressed and have now asked me that I incorporate it into our existing web-site under a tab. I'm confused as to how to proceed. My major problem is that if I maintain the SPA, I don't know how to get it to play nice with routes/urls into the existing (non-Angular) app. If I remove the Angular routing logic to preserve the server-side routing, I lose most of the Angular goodness. Am I missing an obvious solution?

Comment: mixing angularjs and server-side routers can be confusing. but you can still implement angularjs only for specific pages. let the server-side do the routing normally, but in that page call the angular controller to make an http call to get the data from server and display using angular elements.

Comment: I should mention that a huge part of the win of using Angular was ng-resource which handled all the communication with my RESTful back-end.